# iTextSharp XmlWorker Missing Images In Pdf

Tags: itext

I am attempting to use the XmlWorker to convert some HTML to PDF. The HTML text is getting converted to PDF correctly but no images are getting inserted.

I have created a custom IImageProvider class in order to directly access images stored in a database instead of going through an HTML Handler. This should work with no issue, however the methods on my IImageProvider are never getting called aside from the GetImageRootPath method.

I have followed the examples and reviewed them dozens of times and do not understand what I'm doing wrong. I have also used Reflector to debug and step through and seem to have found a problem. This might be a bug in the `HtmlPipelineContext` object or it might be that I'm not using the classes correctly.

Here is my code that is setting up the XmlWorker:

```
var imageProvider = new DatabaseImageProvider();
var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
htmlContext.SetImageProvider(imageProvider);

var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);

var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
              new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, pdfWriter)));

var xmlWorker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
var xmlParser = new XMLParser(xmlWorker);
```

The above code seems pretty standard based on the examples that I've seen. Now, the problems with the images seems to arise from the HtmlPipelineContext objects internal Clone method. The Clone method calls the `GetImageRootPath` method of the currently set ImageProvider, and then replaces the ImageProvider with new ImageProvider of type `CloneImageProvider`. `CloneImageProvider` doesn't really seem to do much with regards to actually fetching images from anywhere given that it doesn't really override much from `AbstractImageProvider`.

```
//This is from iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext
public object Clone()
{
    CssAppliers cloneCssApliers = this.cssAppliers.Clone();
    HtmlPipelineContext newCtx = new HtmlPipelineContext(cloneCssApliers);
    if (this.imageProvider != null)
    {
        String rootPath = imageProvider.GetImageRootPath();
        newCtx.SetImageProvider(new CloneImageProvider(rootPath));
    }
    if (null != this.charset)
    {
        newCtx.CharSet(Encoding.GetEncoding(this.charset.CodePage));
    }
    newCtx.SetPageSize(new Rectangle(this.pageSize)).SetLinkProvider(this.linkprovider)
        .SetRootTags(new List<String>(this.roottags)).AutoBookmark(this.autoBookmark)
        .SetTagFactory(this.tagFactory).SetAcceptUnknown(this.acceptUnknown);
    return newCtx;
}
```

I am at a loss for why `HtmlPipeline` makes a clone of the `HtmlPipelineContext` at all but I really don't care about its implementation. My issue seems to be that the clone returned doesn't carry with it my IImageProvider which I had explicitly set using the `SetImageProvider` method.

Anyone have an ideas on where I'm going wrong here? I can't possibly be the first person to come across this which makes me believe I'm doing something incorrectly here.

Comment: XmlWorker Documentation is telling `XML Worker will only add pictures to the document if they are defined using a fully qualified URL.` So what url you are passing??

Comment: A fully qualified URL in the IMG tag in the format of `http://blah/images/image1.jpg`